# WebGL - Building objects with block

Tags: webgl, three.js

Im trying to build some text using blocks, which I intend to customize later on. The attached image is a mockup of what i intend to do.

I was thinking of using WebGL, since I want to do it in 3D and I cant do any flash, but Im not sure how to contruct the structure of cubes from the letters. Can anyone give me a suggestion or a technique to map text to a series of points so that seen from far aside they draw that same text?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, you need a font — a table of shapes for the characters — in a format you can read from your code. Do you already have one? If it's just a few letters, you could manually create polygons for each character.
2. Then, use a rasterization algorithm to convert the character shape into an array of present-or-absent points/cubes. If you have perfectly flat text, then use a 2D array; if your “customizations” will create depth effects then you will want a 3D array instead (“extruding” the shape by writing it identically into multiple planes of the array).

   An alternative to the previous two steps, which is appropriate if your text does not vary at runtime, is to first create an image with your desired text on it, then use the pixels of the image as the abovementioned 2D array. In the browser, you can do this by using the 2D Canvas feature to draw an image onto a canvas and then reading the pixels out from it.
3. Then to produce a 3D shape from this *voxel* array, construct a polygon face for every place in the array where a “present” point meets an “absent” point. If you do this based on pairs of neighbors, you get a chunky pixel look (like Minecraft). If you want smooth slopes (like your example image), then you need a more complex technique; the traditional way to produce a smooth surface is [marching cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_cubes) (but just doing marching cubes will round off all your corners).

Comment: what could be an example of a font that can be read from code?

Comment: @Dbugger Well, every font format is readable somewhere, or it would be useless, but many would be tedious to read from JavaScript. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the field so I can't recommend a format. (That's why I suggested constructing polygons by hand — it's simple if tedious.) I've also added another option to my answer — you could use a premade image of text and convert that to your cubes.